# Data structure is not modified when calling a method that takes `self`

Tags: struct, rust

I am writing a binary tree structure, and I have problems at the `insert` function. After calling the function to insert data in my node, the node is not modified.

```
use std::ptr;

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Node<T> {
    data: Option<T>,
    left: *mut Node<T>,
    right: *mut Node<T>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn new(data: T) -> Node<T> {
        Node {
            data: Some(data),
            left: ptr::null_mut(),
            right: ptr::null_mut(),
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(mut self, data: T) {
        let tmp = self.data.unwrap();
        self.data = None;

        self.left = &mut Node::new(data);
        self.right = &mut Node::new(tmp);
    }
}

impl<T: std::fmt::Display> std::fmt::Display for Node<T>
    where T: std::fmt::Debug
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self.data {
            Some(ref x) => {
                write!(f, "Node data: {}, left: {}, right: {}", x, 
                        if self.left.is_null() {"null"} else {"not null"}, 
                        if self.right.is_null() {"null"} else {"not null"}, 
                    )
            }
            None => {
                write!(f, "Node data: None, left: {}, right: {}",  
                        if self.left.is_null() {"null"} else {"not null"}, 
                        if self.right.is_null() {"null"} else {"not null"}, 
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut root: Node<i32> = Node::new(32);
    println!("Root before insert : {}", root);
    root.insert(42);
    println!("Root after insert: {}", root);
}
```

And a trace of execution

```
Root before insert : Node data: 32, left: null, right: null
Root after insert : Node data: 32, left: null, right: null
```

My node is not modified after the function insert. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Did you mean `&mut self`, because as it is you are taking the node by value... (which you would have noticed if your `Node` was not `Copy`).

Comment: @MatthieuM. using `&mut self` gives me an error about borrowed content when I try to copy the value in `self.data.unwrap()` into `tmp`

Comment: That's a separate issue; taking `&mut self` is the only way to modify the receptor of the method. Another solution is to take `mut self` and return `Node<T>`, then change the call site to `root = root.insert(...);`. We can help solve either situation, so just pick whichever you prefer.

Comment: I know that returning `Node<T>` is a way to solve the problem, but I want to know if there's a way to do it more OOP-like

Comment: @MatthieuM. this is going to be a sticky question to answer. Note that OP has planted a giant landmine for **memory unsafety** via `self.left = &mut Node::new(data)`. As soon as those values are dereferenced.... **BOOOOOM**.

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne: OOP is a very ill-defined term... may I take it that what you mean is that you'd like `root.insert(...)` to modify `root`, which **requires** taking `&mut self` and you are willing to change the code to make it compile and run correctly?

Comment: @Shepmaster: It's not unsafe, he never dereferences the pointers :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you appear to be quite confused, let's get you started!

First of all, there is no reason to use raw pointers. Furthermore, I advise AGAINST using `Copy` as it just hides ownership issues. Finally, it's much easier to derive `Debug` than implement the formatting manually (and it allows experimenting with the layout of the struct in a more automated fashion).

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    data: Option<T>, // are you sure about using Option here?
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}
```

So, instead of raw pointers, we use a `Box` pointer which we place into an `Option` to handle the null case.

The construction is now:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(data: T) -> Node<T> {
        Node {
            data: Some(data),
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing outstanding, let's move on to `insert`:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn insert(&mut self, data: T) {
        let current = self.data.take().expect("Cannot insert in empty node!");

        self.left = Some(Box::new(Node::new(current)));
        self.right = Some(Box::new(Node::new(data)));
    }
}
```

And we can move on to the display (using `Debug` with `"{:?}"`):

```
fn main() {
    let mut root: Node<i32> = Node::new(32);
    println!("Root before insert : {:?}", root);
    root.insert(42);
    println!("Root after insert: {:?}", root);
}
```

And [it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=06dad4332e7ce48365464f792f2ebb83&version=stable&backtrace=0)!

Comment: Yes, I am sure that `data` needs to be an option for the insertion. Otherwise, do you know why it works with `Box` and not with raw pointers? And thanks for the working answer

Comment: I modified a little bit your code for what I want to do, and [it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d4243b01ef87637a73aa79cc3fe87ec6&version=stable&backtrace=0) like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne: assigning `None` to `self.data` after `take` is unnecessary; `take` is already taking the content of the `Option` and replacing it by `None`. As for raw pointers: you were inadvertently creating a pointer to a variable on the stack, which would have crashed when you tried to dereference it. Raw pointers are powerful, and unsafe (dereferencing them requires the `unsafe` keyword). `Box` instead will put the content on the heap and manage the lifetime for you.